# parsing json encoded array in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am returning a json encoded object to javascript back from PHP and i wish to parse it before displaying it: **However there are a few limitations**.

1.I cannot refer to each individual line such as `user.Relation`, because if the field is empty(and it can be) I will not return it to javascript.
2. I don't know the exact fields that will be returned.
3. It is simply too large to template out even if I did know the individual fields.

when I append it to my div `$('#return').append(data);`

I get

> {"Name":"Mike","Day Phone":"xxx-xxx-xxx","Evening
>   Phone":"xxx-xxx-xxx","Relation":"Parent","Email":"test@test.com","Cell
>   Phone/Pager":"xxx-xxx-xxx"}

which is technically correct, but I want something like :

```
Name: "Mike"
Cell Phone/Pager: "xxx-xxx-xxx"
Day Phone: "xxx-xxx-xxx"
Email: "test@test.com"
Evening Phone: "xxx-xxx-xxx"
Relation: "parent"
...
```

what would be my optimal(fastest) and cleanest way to parse this data out?

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = '';
for (var sAttr in json) {
  s += '<b>'+sAttr+':</b> ' + json[sAttr]+'<br/>';
}
$('#return').append(s);
```

Is what I would do.